# Remove reloading of list fragments when back button is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I created a Tabbed Activity where all the list fragments are pro grammatically created when the activity is first opened as you can see based on previously saved data.

```
public class CcSongBook extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener {
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    SharedPreferences vSettings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor;
    public SongBookSQLite db = new SongBookSQLite(this, SongBookDatabase.DATABASE, null, SongBookDatabase.VERSION);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sb_book);
        vSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        localEditor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(2);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        String[] songbooks = TextUtils.split(vSettings.getString("js_vsb_sbcodes", "NA"), ",");
        String[] songbookno = TextUtils.split(vSettings.getString("js_vsb_sbnos", "NA"), ",");

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return songbooks.length-1;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {            
            return songbooks[position];
        }

        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt("songbook", Integer.parseInt(songbookno[position]));
            SongBookList sblist = new SongBookList();               
            sblist.setArguments(data);
            return sblist;
        }

    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sb_fragment, container, false);
            return rootView;

        }
    }
}
```

then in my other class which is used in list fragments I am basically reading some specific values from my sqlite database based on the bundle data passed on from the base activity:

```
public class SongBookList extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    public SongBookSQLite db;

    private String[] My_Text, My_Texti, My_Textii;
    List<SongItem> mylist;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        db = new SongBookSQLite(getActivity().getBaseContext(), SongBookDatabase.DATABASE, null, SongBookDatabase.VERSION);
        Bundle data = this.getArguments();
        int curr_songbook = data.getInt("songbook", 1);     
        mylist = db.getAllSongs(curr_songbook);

        List<String> listSongid = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> listContent = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
            listSongid.add(i, Integer.toString(mylist.get(i).getSongid()));
            listTitle.add(i, mylist.get(i).getTitle());
            listContent.add(i, mylist.get(i).getContent());
        }

        My_Text = listSongid.toArray(new String[listSongid.size()]);        
        for (String string : My_Text) { System.out.println(string); }

        My_Texti = listTitle.toArray(new String[listTitle.size()]); 
        for (String stringi : My_Texti) {   System.out.println(stringi);}

        My_Textii = listContent.toArray(new String[listContent.size()]);        
        for (String stringii : My_Textii) { System.out.println(stringii);   }

        setListAdapter(new CustomSongList(getActivity(), My_Text, My_Texti, My_Textii));

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {                
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SongBookView.class);
                Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(SongBookProvider.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id+1));
                myIntent.setData(data);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle data) {
        Uri uri = SongBookProvider.CONTENT_URI;
        return new CursorLoader(getContext(), uri, null, null, new String[]{data.getString("query")}, null);
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {
        this.mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(c);
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    }
```

Now when a list item is clicked on any list fragment it opens up in a new activity which is as below:

```
public class SongBookView extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView mSongCont;
    Cursor cursor;
    public Uri mUri;

    SongBookSQLite db;

    SharedPreferences vSettings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor;

    String VSB_SETTINGS, FONT_SIZE, CURRENT_SONG;
    public int CurrSong, FontSize;
    ListView StanzasList;
    SongItem currentSong;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.song_view);
        db = new SongBookSQLite(this, SongBookDatabase.DATABASE, null, SongBookDatabase.VERSION);

        StanzasList =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.stanzalist);

        vSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        localEditor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();

        changeStatusBarColor(); 
        Long rated_me_not = vSettings.getLong("js_vsb_rated_me_not", 0);        
        Long time_used = (System.currentTimeMillis() - rated_me_not) / 1000;

        if  (!PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("js_vsb_rate_me", false)) {
            if (time_used > 18000 ) { 
                rateMePlease();
            }
        }

        FontSize = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("js_vsb_font_size", 15);        

        mUri = getIntent().getData();
        CurrSong = Integer.parseInt(mUri.toString().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));

        openCurrentSong();
    }

    public void openCurrentSong(){
        localEditor.putInt("js_vsb_curr_song", CurrSong).commit();
        currentSong = db.readSong(CurrSong);
        setTitle(currentSong.getTitle());           
        String[] Stanzas = TextUtils.split(currentSong.getContent(), "`");

        CustomSongView adapter = new CustomSongView(this, Stanzas);
        StanzasList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

     @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, CcSongBook.class);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
          startActivity(intent);
          finish();
    }
  }
```

The main question here is how do i prevent the main activity from reloading itself all over again because it is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already seen when the back button is pressed its like a new intent is initiated. How about you removed the line:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, CcSongBook.class);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     startActivity(intent);
```

from the method onBackPressed()

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I thought I needed the line
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); to be able to clear the activity from history so that I reduce the memory consumed by the app

Comment: Well that a different thing altogether because from what I see it is like you wont be able to eat your cake and still have it

Answer (score 0):

Actually removing the lines below did solve my problem

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CcSongBook.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```